# User with "root" privileges can't actually see all folders

Tags: root, permissions, user-accounts

There is this problem with my newly created user with "root" privilages in my web server Ubuntu LTS 12.04 .

I follow the rule:

```
adduser newuser

usermod -a -G sudo newuser
```

then I add in visudo

```
# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
newuser    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL
```

this user is not doing well I only want to access to this this folder:

```
/sites
```

And I can't see the contente via sftp or terminal.

do I jump one more step?

thanks

Answer (score 4):

This doesn't work like that. `sudo` gives a user extended rights if they are requested by calling `sudo`, but you don't have those rights otherwise, and certainly not when connecting to a share via SFTP.

What would work is e.g. `sudo ls -l /sites`, or `sudo cp file /sites` etc., but this isn't possible in a SFTP session.

Read up on how `sudo` works.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation, seems that here, this kind of questions are punished... there is no place for those who are not experts ...

Comment: @Locke: There is a whole network of sites on [SE] where this question would have a much better fit, like [SU] and [unix.se]. [SF] is for pro admins *only* and we make that crystal clear. You chose to ignore this. See the [help] for more informations.